# SAP BO not returning the correct results

Tags: business-objects

I am using SAP BO web intelligence for preparing reports. I am having a problem as some results are missed if even one of the objects I have extracted is missing. I hope you are able to understand my point. For ex. I have asked for Columns S.NO. NAME SURNAME Phone no.

So if any entry doesn't have phone number with them the whole entry is missed.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the query you're using? It's probably due to the data being in different tables, joined together with INNER JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a merged dimension in the report? Generally when we have merged dimension in the report and we do not use the right object(either of the two dimensions merged) this type of problem arises.

Please try merging properly and use the merged dimension in the report.

Let me know if do not solve the problem.